# Cell’s label does not update in UITableView data source

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

When my `UIDatePicker` updates, I call this method:

```
func didUpdateDatePicker(datePicker: UIDatePicker)
{
    birthdayDictionary.setObject(datePicker.date, forKey: EVENT_TYPE_BIRTHDAY_KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: TableViewRows.Date, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
    })
}
```

And my dataSource uses this code:

```
if indexPath.row == TableViewRows.Date
{
    //  Date description
    //
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableViewCellIdentifiers.Date, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Birthday"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = " "

    if let date = birthdayDictionary.objectForKey(EVENT_TYPE_BIRTHDAY_KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH) as NSDate?
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(formatter.stringFromDate(date))"
    }
}
```

Breakpoints tell me that the code all runs as expected and all of the variables change as expected, however, the `detailTextLabel` itself, doesn’t update. I’m calling the `reloadIndexPaths:` method on the main queue to be safe, but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: Does detailTextLabel have a value, is it non-nil? Have you set the IBOutlet for this UILabel in your cell?

Comment: the detailTextLabel is nil. I’m using a right detail uitableviewcell. I should point out that the initial value gets set, but after updating my model and reloading the corresponding row - it doesn’t show the change

Comment: If it is nil then you can't set the text value on it.

Comment: Yeah, but it shouldn’t be nil. It’s a right detail uitableviewcell which has a non-nil detailTextLabel

Comment: How are you creating a right detail UITableViewCell? Where do you register it? Are you using a prototype cell or a subclass?

Comment: A simple prototype cell. As I said, the cell works fine with initial values, but reloading the table after successfully changing the model doesn’t update the detail text label

Comment: As we said, that's because the label is nil. So chances are the wrong type of cell is being dequeued when you reload. Check your identifiers and where you register your cell.

Comment: The odd thing is though, it returns a cell (see docs for why it might return nil) and the index path is 0-0, I.e the first cell in the only section. I only have two cells and they're always on screen. I think I'll see what tableview'a visible cells method returns though. Will keep updated.

Comment: It is returning a cell, but it is not the prototype cell in your storyboards (the cell style which has a detailTextLabel). Did you check your identifiers in Storyboard and code are matching (where you register a class and where you dequeue the cell)?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is remove the `dispatch_async` to see if it's a threading issue. I don't see why you'd need it anyway since the table update data source callbacks should be asynchronous to the calling thread.

Comment: I’ve tried with and without with no luck. The only reason it’s there is to make sure UIKit changes take place on the main thread (as it’s not thread safe)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as `detailTextLabel` is nil, you will not be able to set the text. So this means the cell being returned does not have that label. Chances are you aren't returning the same cell in code as you have created in Storyboards - assuming you are using `UITableViewCell` prototypes.

Make sure the identifier set on your cell prototype matches the identifier in your `self.tableView registerClass:` method.